# Superpowered compile problems with Android NDK-r18

Tags: android-ndk, superpowered

Android Studio has updated the NDK to r-18, which seems to have changed the C++ compiler, but it isn't clear what is wrong. We get the following error:

`CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage`

The samples that comes with Superpowered release 1.2.4 also have this error when using Android Studio 3.2 RC3 with NDK-r18.

What needs to be done to fix the compilation?

Comment: Are you using the CMake that comes with the SDK, or a newer version? It's a weird error to get since the way the NDK toolchain file is written it shouldn't be possible for `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` to get set to nothing.

Comment: Not sure actually, but I'll try to check. This was set up initially with NDK-r17, and from looking into it it seems that it was using a different C++ compiler.

Comment: Have you upgraded the gradle plugin when you shed NDK release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superpowered [uses gnustl](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-iOS-Linux-Windows-tvOS-macOS-Interactive-Audio-Platform/blob/bfdd71e2c18b401b559ecade4e0190f0814546f5/Examples_Android/SuperpoweredPlayer/app/build.gradle#L22) which [has been removed from NDK r18](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history).

A recent [answer](https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-iOS-Linux-Windows-tvOS-macOS-Interactive-Audio-Platform/issues/522#issuecomment-423776205) on GitHub suggests that you can simply set `ANDROID_STL` to **`c++_static`** to resolve the problem with some Superpowered samples. Be careful with this approach, it may have sideeffects at runtime.

It might be safer to stay with NDK r17 until the new release is officially embraced by the library.

Comment: Makes sense. Changing to `c++_static` worked with NDK-r18, however, I think it is good advice to follow up with Superpowered and get the new release that officially supports this compiler. I'm not blocked any more though.

Comment: Android Studio 3.2 and NDK-r18 has just gone GA, and Superpowered just updated their libraries to fix this. If you get the latest SP build this should now be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Superpowered has been updated to NDK r18 and Android Studio 3.2.